# How can I change the returned value of a field in a QuerySet based on some passed parameter?

Tags: django

I want to be able to return different values from a Queryset (not changing the database) based on a parameter. I'd like to be able to write it into the model so that it is enforced everywhere.

If the user is a certain type of user, I would want a QuerySet field to be blank (or "hidden" or something similar).

Here's a simplified Model:

```
class SomeDetails(models.Model):
    size = models.FloatField()
    this_is_okay_to_show = models.TextField()
    not_always_ok = models.TextField()
```

Simplified Queryset:

```
qsSomeDetails = SomeDetails.objects.all()
```

I want not_always_ok to either return the text value stored in the database or return an empty string (or 'hidden' or similar).

Template Filter would work, but it really needs to be in the model.

I'm not sure how to pass a parameter through to make it work.

I feel like the answer is right in front of me, but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

define a `Manager` class for `SomeDetails` model:

```
class SomeDetailsManager(models.Manager):
    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        try:
            return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)
    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)
```

And change your `SomeDetails` like this:

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class SomeDetails(models.Model):
    size = models.FloatField()
    this_is_okay_to_show = models.TextField()
    not_always_ok = models.TextField()
    objects = SomeDetailsManager()

    class QuerySet(QuerySet):
        def get_user(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
            _objects = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
            for obj in _objects:
                if user.username = 'foo': #change with your condition
                    obj.not_always_ok = ''
            return _objects
```

Now you can use

```
qsSomeDetails = SomeDetails.objects.filter(pk=1).get_new_objects(request.user)
```

note:

first done all your filter and use `get_new_objects(request.user)` as last part.

Comment: I should not have included "user" in my sample Model. I am looking for a condition on the logged in user, not the user from the model. I'll edit my example.

How do I get "user_has_condidtion" to evaluate based on the user making the request (request.user)? I guess that's the part I'm struggling with. I know I'm missing something that is right in front of my face. How do I get that parameter to evaluate at run time.

Comment: @user791770 check my edit. you access to requested user object in `get_new_objects`.

Comment: That works but if I add a filter to the returned queryset, it reverts back to the original value. SomeDetails.objects.get_new_objects(request.user).filter(pk=1) returns the original value, not the masked/hidden value.

Comment: @user791770 again check my edit. I hope this help you.